# No web3.min.js while download Zip file from Github

Tags: web3js, blockchain, tutorials, clone

I am following a [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KkZ6iYnSDRw&t=681s) tutorial to make a simple dApp. In this tutorial he is telling to get [Web3 from GitHub](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/). I downloaded the Zip of Web3 from the GitHub and i get following folders and file after decompressing it.

[image]

But in the tutorial he is referring to a `.js` file named `web3.min.js` in his `html` code. I searched all the above folders to get `web3.min.js` but i didn't find it.

Is there any way to get `web3.min.js` from the downloaded Zip file? OR if i have to clone it to get `web3.min.js` then how i can clone it from GitHub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no dist folder (containing the web3.min.js file) in the latest versions (1.x)
You can select tag 0.20.7 on github before downloading the zip - it contains a ready to use web3.min.js

Comment: I am new to GitHub. How i can select tag 0.20.7?

Comment: Just found it, Thanks....Please up-vote my question if you think it will be helpful for others.